# Rename files to md5 sum + extension on Windows 7 (with CMD or PowerShell 2013)

Tags: powershell, cmd, md5, rename

I'm struggling to come up with a solution. All so far have been crutches since I cannot get my tools only to output the plain md5 string, to write it into a variable 2 and use it later on to rename the file I stored in a variable 1.

The solutions I found are for *nix or PHP and were not helpful with my problem.

Comment: What have you got so far? Show some code and it's easier to help with specific an issue.

Comment: You might like this image renaming powershell script: https://gist.github.com/thorade/5970020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't write what you've already got, so I won't explain the script. Just remember that you'll get an error for files with same md5.

```
Get-ChildItem d:\temp\*.xxx | select FullName, Extension, @{name='md5'; expression={(Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm md5).Hash}} | foreach {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.md5)$($_.extension)"}
```